Azure DevOps | Deploy Azure App Service succeeds, but agent doesn't get feedback
I have created two pipelines in my DevOps environment, the first one is a "build" pipeline, which gets triggered when i commit to the develop branch. This pipeline runs successfully and creates an artifact of my application (NodeJs + Angular). This works, nothing special here.
After creating the artifact, a "release" pipeline get's triggered, this pipeline only downloads the artifact and then deploys it using ZIP deploy:
******************************************************************************
Starting: Deploy Azure App Service
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure App Service deploy
Description  : Deploy to Azure App Service a web, mobile, or API app using Docker, Java, .NET, .NET Core, Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby
Version      : 4.240.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azureappservicetroubleshooting
==============================================================================
Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'app-contoso-dev'
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.

When i look in the logs of my App Service (Deployment Center page) i can see that the deployment is executed and successful after about 20 minutes. I can confirm that everything works and is updated properly.
The last message i can see in the logs on the deployment center page is:
Deployment successful. deployer = VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY deploymentPath = ZipDeploy. Extract zip.`
However, it looks like my agent is not receiving any feedback of the successful deployment, causing it to fail after about 6 hours! (I use a self hosted agent).
After 6 hours and 12 minutes i am getting this error:
We stopped hearing from agent Hosted Agent. Verify the agent machine is running 
and has a healthy network connection. Anything that terminates an agent process, 
starves it for CPU, or blocks its network access can cause this error.

I already searched for a solution but i am not able to find one, I also cannot figure out how the agent should know that the deployment was successful.

Does it happen all the time? Maybe any recent issue has caused this strange behaviour?

@RuiJarimba Yes, it happens all the time, at least for the past three days.

BTW with or without weird issues, consider setting Job Timeouts.

@RuiJarimba Thanks for your feedback, I don't want to set a timeout, because that won't solve the problem unfortunately. I understand that it can be caused by outages and I value your opinion although I think there must be another reason for this issue.

Timeouts are not meant to solve the problem - the idea is to mitigate it, to avoid taking up resources when your job is unresponsive or waiting too long. The sooner you free up the agent the sooner it can process another job.

@Napinator, This is a common error when agent service is terminated unexpected. I have added the details below. let me know if you have any queries.


We stopped hearing from agent Hosted Agent. Verify the agent machine is running
and has a healthy network connection. Anything that terminates an agent process,
starves it for CPU, or blocks its network access can cause this error.

This is a common error when agent process is terminated unexpected.
When you run pipeline with self-hosted agent, the CPU, RAM, Disk could be not enough, network issue happens on the machine, or the agent process is terminated by other service, it will cause connection lost from the Agent to DevOps, then the error will report. Also, you could have the timeout setting on the job, and error reported after 6hours.
You need to check the pipeline debug log, and two diagnostic logs on agent(Worker diagnostic logs and Agent diagnostic logs) to find the error details.
You can create a new agent with different network, and better hardware for a check.

There could many logs on self-hosted agent, you can backup the existing logs to other place and then clear the log folder. Rerun the pipeline to replicate the issue, it will automatically create the new log for you. Then you can check the details.
